# tcp client in julia with tcp server in java

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, client, julia

I wrote a simple TCP socket server in Java (code below), which is basically an echo server (but replaces 'a' with 'b')

Now I am trying to write the client using Julia

I can send a message on the Julia cilent, this arrives in Java

**But I do not see the response in Julia that the Java echo server sends**

What am I doing wrong?

==========================

Using Julia 0.4.1-pre

Julia client on REPL:

```
clientside=connect(4445)
println(clientside,"aaa") # on output; expected output here due to example on docs 
println(readline(clientside)) # no output here either, in fact, this blocks
```

Java server:

```
try
        (
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
                DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());
        )
        {
            String line = null;
            while((line = input.readLine()) != null)
            {
                output.writeUTF(line.replace('a','b'));
                if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you debugged your java code to see that the java server is accepting/receiving input?

Comment: yes, java code receives the correct input...that code runs through no problem...but nothing arrives in julia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it to work

I changed the Java DataOutputStream to a PrintWriter

I don't understand it, but at least it works

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to flush your DataOutputStream.

Comment: I did try that, did not help